# How can I use PropertyGroupDescription with a related table column, when sorting a listbox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to group my list by a related tables property name lightType. So I tried the PropertyGroupDescription "RelatedPhantoms[0].lightType.Name" but it does not seem to find the property. How can I fix this?

```
            ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MainLightList.ItemsSource);
            view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("RelatedPhantoms[0].lightType.Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("lightSeries.Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));


            view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("RelatedPhantoms[0].lightType.Name"));
            view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("lightSeries.Name"));
```

the following is the data backing this collection of lights

```
public class LightHead : CoreEntity
{
    public LightHead()
    {

        this.RelatedPhantoms = new List<LightHead>();
        this.OtherRelatedPhantoms = new List<LightHead>();

    }

    public LightSeries lightSeries { get; set; }

       public Nullable<int> LightSeriesId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LightHead> RelatedPhantoms { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LightHead> OtherRelatedPhantoms { get; set; }


}
}


public class LightSeries: CoreModelEntity
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public ICollection<LightHead> lightHeads { get; set; }

     public LightType lightType { get; set; }
     public Nullable<int> LightTypeId { get; set; }

     public LightSeries() { }
     public LightSeries(string name) 
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it public & a property? perhaps sharing the data model may help.

Comment: Yes, and okay I will add it

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that an ICollection does not support indexing (so RelatedPhantoms[0] is not valid). Have you tried to replace it by a List or an array.

Answer (score 0):

`RelatedPhantoms` is a collection of `LightHead` and `lightType` is a property of `LightSeries`

so `"RelatedPhantoms[0].lightType.Name"` may not work

as `LightHead` class contains `lightSeries` property of type `LightSeries` which has the property `lightType`

so you may change the property description to

```
"RelatedPhantoms[0].lightSeries.lightType.Name"
```

above is based on some assumptions after looking the posted code. you may adjust the same as needed.

it is also worth to verify that the collection RelatedPhantoms is of type `IList<T>` to support indexers

also verify that if `RelatedPhantoms` collection is supposed to be of Type `LightHead` or `LightSeries` as a lightHeads collection in LightSeries do exists, which make me think of relation between these classes